# When a date appears in one field, make it also appear in a second field at the same time MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

When a user selects a date in the below HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PPEDueDate, "PPE Due Date", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PPEDueDate, new { @class = "datepicker5", id = "datepicker5" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PPEDueDate)
                </div>
            </div>
```

Then the field below should automatically be populated too.

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PPET_PPEDueDate, "PPE Due Date", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PPET_PPEDueDate, new { @class = "datepicker28", id = "datepicker28" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PPET_PPEDueDate)
                </div>
            </div>
```

My datepickers are populated by

```
<script>
                $(function () {

                    $("#datepicker5").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });

                    $("#datepicker28").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
                                   });                           
            </script>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to copy the value from your first datepicker to your second datepicker using JQuery:

```
$('#datepicker5').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $('#datepicker28').val(dateText);
    }
});
```

## JSFiddle here

Comment: Your codes works on JSFiddle but when I implemented it into my solution it doesn't work

Comment: I'm gonna need more information if you want me to help you, why doesn't it work? The only reason this wouldn't work is if you weren't referencing the JQuery and JQueryUI libraries.

Comment: I have <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>, all included because I need these to make the datepickers function

Comment: When I placed your JS into my create view, and selected datepicker 5 and chose a date, datepicker28 wasn't populated

Comment: Press F12 in your browser and go to console, then select a date in `datepicker5` again. Tell me what the error is.

Comment: uh .. I have no idea then. Would appreciate it if you accepted the answer assuming my code does what it's meant to, I don't know why it doesn't work in your solution though.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
$('#datepicker5').datepicker({
     dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
     changeMonth: true, 
     changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText){
            $("#datepicker28").val(dateText);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the datepicker28 field and reconfigured datepicker 5 like this

```
$("#datepicker5").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, onClose: function (dateseletced) { $("#datepicker28").val(dateseletced) } });
```

onSelect allowed the date selected in datepicker 5 be transferred automatically to datepicker 28.

I disabled datepicker 28 to ensure the user can't write in it.

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PPET_PPEDueDate, "PPE Due Date", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PPET_PPEDueDate, new { @class = "datepicker28", id = "datepicker28", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PPET_PPEDueDate)
                </div>
            </div>
```